# How can i embed a css hover effect on an image in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image, mousehover

im trying to embed an image with a css hover on my wordpress site. But cant seem to wrap my head around how to embed the code.

The last code on this page called "chico" is the one im trying to embed. https://github.com/codrops/HoverEffectIdeas/blob/master/css/set1.css

can someone explain to me how i can put this on my image.

Comment: copy all the needful CSS for that class, change your HTML class according to the CSS and it will work.

Comment: follow these instructions https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/

Comment: how can i define the HTML class and link it to the CSS class?